# Trying to understand closures. Could somebody walk me through this code?

Tags: javascript, closures

Here's a bit of javascript taken from [this reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/gxn7t/closures_explained_with_javascript/c1r58o5):

```
function Stream() {
    var data       = [],
        listeners  = [];

    function push( new_data ) {
        var result = data.push( new_data );
        callListeners( new_data, result );
        return result;
    }

    function addListener( listener ) {
        return listeners.push( listener );
    }

    function callListeners( ) {
        var length    = listeners.length,
            result    = [],
            action    = null;
        while ( length-- ) {
            action = listeners[ length ];
            result.push( action.apply( null, arguments) );
        }
        return result;
    }

    return {
        push : push,
        addListener: addListener
    }

}


var foo = Stream();
foo.addListener( function( new_data ) {
    alert( "added: " + new_data );
});
foo.push( "Hello World!" );
```

I think I have a tenuous grasp on Closures after reading [this tutorial](http://skilldrick.co.uk/2011/04/closures-explained-with-javascript/), but I just can't figure out how this code works. When I try to parse it in my head, I basically get stuck at line 6: `var result = data.push( new_data );`.

<strike>It seems with `data` simply being an array at that point `data.push( foo )` doesn't make sense. And wouldn't it recurse infinitely anyway?</strike> (strike that -- didn't know there was a native `push` method for arrays) Very next line `callListener` is called with two parameters, but below the function has none.

If someone's got a few minutes, could you grab my hand and walk me through this code like the ignorant dolt I am? Right now, I'm not even sure I understand the destination.

Comment: why would it be infinite? arrays have a native `push` method and that code is not calling `function push( new_data )`

Comment: @Hristo - I didn't know there was a native method. I thought this referred to the push function.

Comment: @Greg... well that is an easy fix :) check out my answer

Comment: nope; it's the array's push function.  I could see how you could be confused - this is a weak programming decision, in my opinion.  It would be better to call it something like `stack` or `store`.  Something generic that isn't as commonly used as Array.push

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays *are* objects, and they have a `push()` method.  Nothing unusual there.

The `callListeners()` function doesn't declare any named parameters, but JavaScript allows functions to be called with more parameters than they're declared to take, and the full list of arguments is available as the special name `arguments`.  `callListeners()` uses `arguments` in an `action.apply()` call, to invoke the `action` function with the same list of arguments that `callListeners()` itself was given.  The purpose of `callListeners()` is that you call it with some arguments, and it calls all the functions in the `listeners` array with those arguments.

Neither of those things is really related to the use of closures, though.  The place where closures come into play is that the object returned by `Stream()` has two methods, `push()` and `addListener()`, that can "see" the same `data` and `listeners` arrays even though those arrays aren't stored in the object that the methods are called on.  Two calls to `Stream()` will return two objects whose methods see *different* `data` and `listeners` arrays.

Answer (score 3):

```
> function Stream() {
>     var data       = [],
>         listeners  = [];
> 
>     function push( new_data ) {
>         var result = data.push( new_data );
```

`data` is a reference to data in the outer function. The return value from `data.push(...)` is the length of the array after `new_data` has been added.

```
>         callListeners( new_data, result );
>         return result;
>     }
```

`callListeners()` is a call to the function declared with that name below.

```
>     function addListener( listener ) {
>         return listeners.push( listener );
>     }
```

This adds `listener` to `listeners` and returns the new length of the `listeners` array.

```
>     function callListeners( ) {
>         var length    = listeners.length,
>             result    = [],
>             action    = null;
>         while ( length-- ) {
>             action = listeners[ length ];
>             result.push( action.apply( null, arguments) );
>         }
>         return result;
>     }
```

The above function calls all the listeners in the `listeners` array with the arguments that have been passed to it. It calls them in reverse order though (i.e. the last one added is called first, then the second last, and so on), which is a bit unusual.

```
>     return {
>         push : push,
>         addListener: addListener
>     }
```

Returns an object with properties `push` (whose value is a reference to the function declared with the name *push*), and `addListener` (whose value is a reference to the function declared with the name *addListener*)

```
> }
> 
> 
> var foo = Stream();
```

By convention, functions whose name starts with a capital letter are constructors and should be called with the `new` operator. *Stream* is not a constructor so should start with a lower case s.

```
> foo.addListener( function( new_data )
> {
>     alert( "added: " + new_data ); });
```

That calls `foo.addListener` (which is a reference to the "closed over" *addListener* function created when `Stream()` was called above) and passes it an anonymous function. Nothing is done with the return value.

```
> foo.push( "Hello World!" );
```

That calls the (closed over) `push` function and passes it the string "Hello World!". `push` then calls `callListeners()`, passing it the same string. `callListeners` then calls every function in the listeners array (there's only one so far, the anonymous function added above), passing it the parameters supplied to `push()` (i.e. "Hello World!").

So the result is an alert with "added: Hello World!".

If you add another listener, then calling `foo.push()` will call both listeners with the supplied arguments, but in the reverse order to which they were added.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is a method on the Array class:

> Mutates an array by appending the given elements and returning the new length of the array.

So `var result = data.push( new_data );` just appends `new_data` to `data` and sets `result` to the new number of elements in `data`.

The `callListeners` bit is tricky. The `action` will be a function and it will be called by using the [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply) method on that function (note: functions are objects in JavaScript). You'll also see [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/functions_and_function_scope/arguments) in there, that's a special variable that is:

> An array-like object corresponding to the arguments passed to a function.

So, if you want to unpack the argument list yourself (like using `@_` in Perl, or variable argument lists in C or C++) or if you're just planning on passing the full argument list to someone else that wants an array, then you can use `arguments`. Normally you'd say:

```
var a = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
```

To explicitly convert the `arguments` to a real array. However, in this case `apply` is happy to take a raw `arguments` pseudo-array so there's no need for the "slice cast".

Comment: Heh. That callListeners function is actually almost as clever as it was confusing.

Comment: Array is a **Function** object, it is not a "class". `push` is a method of *Array.prototype*, not *Array*. You could say it is a method of an Array instance - which is like a class method, but there are no classes in javascript. :-)

Comment: @Greg - presumably the arguments passed to `foo.push()` should be generic for all listeners, say `event` and `this` (i.e. the element on which the listener should be called).

Comment: @RobG: Yes, `Array instanceof Function` if you want to be pedantic. OTOH, `[1] instanceof Array` so referring to Array as a class is reasonable and fairly common. I don't see much point in confusing someone with a bunch of noise on prototype based inheritance until after they've wrapped their head around closures, implicit argument lists, and "functions as objects".

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript arrays have a native `push()` method. Check out this article...

http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays

... so the code isn't calling `function push( new_data ){}` recursively, it is referring to the array's native `push()` method.

If it was recursive, it would instead be `var result = this.push( new_data );` which would make it infinite :)

I hope this helps.
Hristo

Comment: Thanks. I'm still confused about the following line though. How is `callListeners( new_data, result );` valid if the function is defined having no parameters?

Comment: @Greg... in regard to the `callListeners()`, check out Wyzard's answer.

Comment: @Greg, because within `callListeners`, the name `arguments` automatically refers to a 2-element array containing those two values.